# Can anyone help figure out whats wrong with my file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I am playing PC Minecraft, and I know I saved my file while I was in a safe spot the last time I played.

I went to the same file today and I can't see anything, the whole screen was grey and I just start dying right after I have been loaded onto the file.

How do I fix it? I want to continue on this file because I did so much, but this is the second time this happened to me on another file. Is this some kind of bug or glitch?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Sounds like a rendering issue try lowering all of your video settings

Comment: Screenshot or world file could help.

Comment: I will close to vote this, Arqade is not the place to ask for help over your life problems and... Oh, wait...

Post here a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a spawning problem, and your spawning underground. Switch to creative mode (using /gamemode 1) and destroy the stone, if its not stone you might be spawning in the void. If so, fly up, or use /tp, to go back to base, then change your spawnpoint using either /spawnpoint or a bed. If you still have problems (and used a bed) destroy the bed and then you should spawn back at your original spawnpoint. I hope this has been helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

## Main Idea: `/gamemode 1` and MCEdit

Hi,

Here's a suggestion: Use `/gamemode 1` (as suggested in previous answers). If that doesn't work, try using [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/downloads.html). Find your Minecraft save file (generally in `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves` - you can look that up in the search bar in the Start Menu), open the folder with your world with it, and then open `level.dat` using MCEdit. (MCEdit->Open->(navigate to folder)->level.dat) Basic controls are `WASDQZ`. Find where your player spawnpoint is (usually a box with a player head in it), set the blocks around it to air and save the world. Open up Minecraft and load the world again. If you still have no luck, send screenshots.

Hope that helps, HewwoCraziness